# Display a list of all attributes in opencart

Tags: php, list, attributes, opencart

I want to display a list of all attributes that are added into database but every time I try something it doesn't work. I want to show this inside a div from the from the front page. I tried to insert this into featured.tpl:

```
<?php 
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
echo $attribute_group['name'];
print_r($attribute_group);
echo '<select name="listaGrupe">';
foreach ($attribute_groups['attribute'] as $attribute) {
echo '<option value="'.$attribute.'">'.$attribute.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ned to use this model

```
public function getAttributes($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT *, (SELECT agd.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_group_description agd WHERE agd.attribute_group_id = a.attribute_group_id AND agd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS attribute_group FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute a LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "attribute_description ad ON (a.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id) WHERE ad.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
        $sql .= " AND LCASE(ad.name) LIKE '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "%'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_attribute_group_id'])) {
        $sql .= " AND a.attribute_group_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_attribute_group_id']) . "'";
    }

    $sort_data = array(
        'ad.name',
        'attribute_group',
        'a.sort_order'
    );  

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];   
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY attribute_group, ad.name";   
    }   

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC";
    }

    if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
        if ($data['start'] < 0) {
            $data['start'] = 0;
        }               

        if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
            $data['limit'] = 20;
        }   

        $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
    }   

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

The in your controller simply load this model and manipulate with the data it returns. By default it returns all the attributes in database

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a function format closer to this:

```
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
$options = '';
$name = $attribute_group['name'];
$output = '<select name="$name">';
foreach ($attribute_groups['attribute'] as $attribute) {
$options .= '<option value="'.$attribute.'">'.$attribute.'</option>';
}
echo $output.$options.'</select>';
}
```

Comment: Even if I try my method or yours I get this error

Notice: Undefined variable: attribute_groups in /home/ssdesign/public_html/auto-dvn/catalog/view/theme/unistore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 27Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ssdesign/public_html/auto-dvn/catalog/view/theme/unistore/template/module/featured.tpl on line 27

Comment: @CatalinDragosVladulescu I can only work with the information you provide. I don't know how you are writing the query to your database, nor do I know the database structure. If you edit your original post to provide this information, I may be able to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

check in your controller .. if $attribute_groups have datas in it....

print_r($attribute_groups);

and see.. make sure your $attribute_groups array is not empty... i think u getting that error since your $attribute_groups array is empty...

if incase you are sure, $attribute_groups can be empty then u can check ...

```
if(!empty($attribute_groups)){
foreach ($attribute_groups as $attribute_group) {
$options = '';
$name = $attribute_group['name'];
$output = '<select name="$name">';
foreach ($attribute_groups['attribute'] as $attribute) {
$options .= '<option value="'.$attribute.'">'.$attribute.'</option>';
}
echo $output.$options.'</select>';
}
}
```

this will see if your array is empty or not.. if not then foreach()... else do nothing